# google.maps.FusionTablesMouseEvent - how to access the info window object?

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables, infowindow

I need to access an `InfoWindow` object after the user clicks on the map. Unfortunately, the supplied event object only provides the `.infoWindowHtml` attribute, which lets me customize the `InfoWindow` contents, but does not let me do anything with info window itself. Is there any way to get the object from JavaScript?

Alternately, I would be perfectly happy open my own `InfoWindow` from the start. But I can neither stop the Fusion Tables `InfoWindow` from opening, nor stop it after it has opened. If I open my own, it's just displayed above the stock one. Of course, if my info window will always be bigger, I can just ignore the Fusion Tables info window, but there has to be a better way.

---

Background: actually, I just need to dynamically load `InfoWindow` contents. Through some jQuery magic I managed to get to my contents element and change it, but `InfoWindow` doesn't resize itself, unfortunately, making the content overflow nastily. I hope that if I get to the `InfoWindow` object and set the content through it, it will resize itself as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To suppress the automatic FusionTablesLayer InfoWindows, use the suppressInfoWindows:true [option](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesLayerOptions) in the FusionTablesLayers constructor